# Dynamic C # Subscribe to an event is lost on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

Folks, I have a simple list of objects by dynamically, to which each object will subscribe an event to trigger to make you click.

That event, what it does is remove that object from the base and then again renderize objects, in which the event should again resubscribe.

```
private void BindTable()
    {
        PersonsManager manager = new PersonsManager();
        pnlPersons.Controls.Clear();

        foreach (var person in Persons)
        {
            PersonControl personControl = (PersonControl)Page.LoadControl("~/Widgets/PersonControl.ascx");
            personControl.Person = person;
            personControl.BeginSelect += new SelectPersonEventHandler(personControl_BeginSelect);

            pnlPersons.Controls.Add(personControl);
        }

    }

protected void personControl_BeginSelect(object sender, SelectPersonEventArgs e)
    {
        PersonsManager manager = new PersonsManager();
        manager.DeletePerson(e.Person.Id);
        Persons.Remove(e.Person);

        BindTable();
    }
```

The issue is that once triggered the event for the first time it postback and reloads the list. But if I want to shoot the event again in another item, I make two clicks to work!.

As could get to fix this? Got it?

I hope I can help!
Greetings!

Comment: This is an English language site, Diego. Please repost your question in English.

Comment: Este es un sitio en el idioma Inglés, Diego. Por favor, informe a su pregunta en Inglés.

Comment: Done. Sorry for the inconvenience!